# Custom metrics for multiclass classification when class errors have different weights

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, metrics

I have a multiclass classification problem (eg. the target variable is made by 4 different outcomes: Product A, Product B, Product C and NO Product). Not all the errors are equal: for example, if the true label is "Product A" and the prediction is "NO Product" it is not a big problem, while if the true label is "Product C" the impact of the error is much bigger. Basically, I have to insert this information into the loss function of the algorithm (I am currently using Xg-Boost, Random Forest, ecc).

Any idea on how to implement it on scikit-learn or other ML libraries on Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this the mapping of your classes:

```
{'Product A':0, 'Product B':1, 'Product C':2, 'NO Product':3)}
```

Then from [`sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) docs, use `class_weight` as follows:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100, class_weight = {0:1,1:1,2:2,3:1})
```

This will give more weights to `'Product C'`

Comment: Great, thank you! Is there the possibility to say, for example, that a miss-classification of product C in Product B is more problematic w.r.t a miss-classification of Product C to Product B? I mean something like a dict of dict like {0: {1:1, 2: 1, 3:2}, 1:{...}, ...} such that an error of product 0 is more penalized if assigned to group 3.

Comment: I got your point but I think the class_weight only gives high weights to class in focus, there could be any other algorithm which penalize the model for making cross predictions, you might need do a lot of googling for that or create a new post at Cross Validated which is a better place for data science queries.

Comment: Perfect. FYI I post the question even on Cross Validated and you can found here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/459239/custom-metrics-for-multiclass-classification-when-class-errors-have-different-we)